# How to create a menu/tab in Android application?

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, tabs

I'm fairly new to Java and Android studio, but I'm learning how to make a simple app with some buttons. My application has a bunch of buttons now though, so I thought it would look much nicer if I split up the buttons into two windows/tabs using a menu of some sort. Right now, my xml file looks like this:

```
<Relative layout....
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Option 1"
    android:id="@+id/opt1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="option 2"
    android:id="@+id/opt2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/opt2"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Option 3"
    android:id="@+id/opt3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Option 4"
    android:id="@+id/opt4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/opt2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="Say something..."
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/opt2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:editable="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="option 5"
    android:id="@+id/opt5"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Option 6"
    android:id="@+id/opt6"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Option 7"
    android:id="@+id/opt7"

    android:enabled="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Option 8"
    android:id="@+id/opt8"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:enabled="false"
    />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

In my main activity class, I have action listeners for all these buttons in the    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method. But now, the layout is too cluttered and I want to move buttons 5-8 and the EditText object to another tab or window of some sort, but I don't know how to do that. Is there a simple way to go about this? Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Go to the android developer site and start from the beginning... Android's UI elements are well-established, and once you know how your navigation should work, this is easy to implement based on their tutorials. Good luck!

Comment: Is there a specific tutorial you would recommend?

Comment: You'll have to do your own googling, friend. Questions asking for recommendations for off-site resources are off-topic here.

Comment: Refer : [Link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)